# Changing the property of base object

Tags: javascript

I have an example, after the line `toy.type = 'break';`I was expecting the next line would give me the value as "break" but instead gave "soft". Why isnt changing the parent property not reflecting when accessed using child object . Isnt the prototypal inheritance just a refernce to the base object?

```
const toy = {
    init : function(type)
  {
    this.type = type
  },
  display : function()
  {
    console.log(this.type)
  }
}

const softToy = Object.create(toy);
softToy.init('soft');
softToy.display();
toy.type = 'break';
softToy.display();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access an object, JavaScript searches up the prototype chain until it finds an object with that property.

Because `softToy` has its own `type` property, you get the value of that. If it **didn't** have its own `type` property then the prototype chain would be followed to the `toy` object and the `type` property from there would be accessed instead.

---

In other words, you get the **closest** version of the property not the most recently changed version.

Comment: Isnt "type" a property of toy object? Softtoy is just inheriting this as "Prototype" right from toy object?

Comment: @User1267 — `toy.type = 'break';` sets a type property on the toy object. `this.type = type` sets it on whatever `this` is which, when you call `softToy.init('soft');
` is `softToy`.